# Google distance matrix API. How to access an alternative routes?

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

I use google distance matrix api for get distance from point "a" to point "b". The problem is that I can't get an alternative routes. Google maps does not show a different(alternative) path. Only one.

I use google distance matrix api, can there be any way to get an alternative route? Maybe there is another api that will give the alternative data?

Answer (score 0):

The distance matrix doesn't have any way to provide alternative routes.  If you need alternative routes, you need to use the Directions Service.